# How to find an element that DOES NOT have a class

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO framework. And in my script I am working with the calendar and I need to get only days from the current month. Here is the html snippet:

```html
<tr class="daysrow">
    <td class="day wn">13</td>
    <td class="day weekend">4</td>
    <td class="day">5</td>
    <td class="day">6</td>
    <td class="day">7</td>
    <td class="day">8</td>
    <td class="day">9</td>
    <td class="day weekend">10</td>
</tr>
```

If I use $$(tr.daysrow td.day) I will get 35 days instead of 30. That is because numbers of the weeks also have ".day" class. So I need to exclude in my command all elements having class ".wn". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
$$(tr.daysrow td.day:not(.wn))
```